# How to get \clearpage and \rowcolor to work together in a longtable?

Tags: longtable, rowcolor, clearpage

I have this multi-page `longtable` where I need to nudge a row over to the next page for layout purposes. Normally I'd just start the row with `\clearpage` (and this has worked elsewhere) but this time I need to `\rowcolor` the row. If I put the `\clearpage` before the `\rowcolor`, I get a `"! Misplaced \noalign. \rowcolor ->\noalign"` error. If I swap them, I get a `"! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit"` error. I had to resort to inserting blank rows to achieve the page-clearing, like so:

```
{\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{9.6cm}|}
\caption{Description...\label{tab22}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue}
\textbf{Tâche}&\textbf{Responsabilité}&\textbf{Description}\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\rowcolor{blue}
\textbf{Tâche}&\textbf{Responsabilité}&\textbf{Description}\\\hline
\endhead %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Création d’une ébauche&
Premier auteur&
Le premier auteur rédige une ébauche du document...\\\hline %%%%%%%%%
Communication&
Éditeur externe&
L’éditeur externe informe l’auteur que la publication...\\\hline %%%%
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\vspace{8mm}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\hfill}\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Si le document est refusé}\\\hline %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
Communication du refus&
Premier auteur&
Le premier auteur informe le Bureau de la rédaction...\\\hline %%%%%%
\end{longtable}
}
```

While I wanted something like:

```
{\small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{9.6cm}|}
\caption{Description...\label{tab22}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{blue}
\textbf{Tâche}&\textbf{Responsabilité}&\textbf{Description}\\\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\rowcolor{blue}
\textbf{Tâche}&\textbf{Responsabilité}&\textbf{Description}\\\hline
\endhead %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Création d’une ébauche&
Premier auteur&
Le premier auteur rédige une ébauche du document...\\\hline %%%%%%%%%
Communication&
Éditeur externe&
L’éditeur externe informe l’auteur que la publication...\\\hline %%%%
\clearpage
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Si le document est refusé}\\\hline %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}
Communication du refus&
Premier auteur&
Le premier auteur informe le Bureau de la rédaction...\\\hline %%%%%%
\end{longtable}
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the newer tabularray package; see [its documentation](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf). It has different methods for inserting page breaks and coloring things, but you can do both at the same time quite easily:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{small}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={Description\ldots},% set caption
    label={tab22}% set label
]
{
    colspec={Q[m,wd=2.2cm]Q[m,wd=2.5cm]Q[m,wd=9.6cm]},
    colsep=4pt,
    rowhead=0, % header rows to repeat on each page
    hlines, % horizontal lines between rows
    vlines, % veritcal rows between columns
    hborder{4} = {pagebreak=yes}, % page break before the 4th row
    row{1} = {bg=blue,fg=gray8},% make first row blue
    row{4-5} = {bg=gray8} % make 4th and 5th rows gray
}
    \textbf{Tâche}&\textbf{Responsabilité}&\textbf{Description}\\
    Création d’une ébauche&
    Premier auteur&
    Le premier auteur rédige une ébauche du document\ldots\\
    Communication&
    Éditeur externe&
    L’éditeur externe informe l’auteur que la publication \ldots\\
    \SetCell[c=3]{c}{Si le document est refusé} & & \\
    Communication du refus&
    Premier auteur&
    Le premier auteur informe le Bureau de la rédaction \ldots
\end{longtblr}
\end{small}

\end{document}
```

[image: table split across pages]